# Dynamic function arguments?

Tags: python, function

I am using data from an api, which gives me infos about players from a clan, like their tag.
More data would be required from each individual player, which can be done by making another api call to the "players" path, including their tag.
Since the clan has a lot of members, which could change, I was thinking about a dynamic function that automatically takes the pulls the tag from each player, and inserts it into the url.

Is this possible?
Cause otherwise I would need to call the function manually(new to python).

```
member_tags = ["12345", "61244", "66334"]

def import_requests(path, tag):
  url = "https://....../<+path+>"

  url = url.replace("<+path+>", path)

    url = url + "/" + tag

    print(url)

    import requests
import_requests("clans", "12345")
```

In this example, the "12345" tag should be inserted into import_requests, then "61244" etc.

Comment: Just use string formatting: `url = f'https://..../{path}/{tag}'`

Comment: Thx, will try that

Comment: now you have to use `for`-loop to run function for different values in `member_tags` - `for tag in member_tags: import_requests("clans", tag)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I uderstand your problem but you need `f-string` to generate urls with different `tag`

```
url = f'https://...../{path}/{tag}'
```

And `for`-loop to run `import_requests()` with different `tag` from `member_tags`

Something like this:

```
import requests  # PEP8: all imports at the beginning of code

# --- constants ---

BASE = "https://......"

# --- functions ---

def import_requests(path, tag):
    url = f'{BASE}/{path}/{tag}'
    print(url)
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response.data)

# --- main ---

member_tags = ["12345", "61244", "66334"]

for tag in member_tags: 
    import_requests("clans", tag)
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)